# Bash herefile with backslash different result on ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04?

Tags: bash, shell, backslash

I want to put a longer text into a shellscript variable and used herefile and backslash like in the following example. I see different behaviour with ubuntu 18.04 and ubuntu 20.04 (both use /bin/bash, utf-8:

```
param="$(cat <<'EOF'
a\
b
EOF
)"
echo $param > ./testfile.txt
```

output (cat ./testfile.txt) on ubuntu 18.04:

```
ab
```

output on ubuntu 20.04:

```
a\ b
```

Why is the output different?

PS: using EOF instead of 'EOF' the output is with both versions:

```
ab
```

Comment: What's the $BASH_VERSION on each system?

Comment: 4.4.20(1)-release on ubuntu 18.04 and 5.0.17(1)-release on ubunut 20.04

Comment: Might be similar to [this herestring issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63605431/bash-3-and-bash-5-evaluate-herestring-whitespace-differently)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug fix in version 5.0:

> kk. Fixed a bug that caused bash to remove backslash-newline pairs from the
> body of a here-document with a quoted delimiter inside a command
> substitution.

In 4.4, it was removed, so that `cat` saw `a` and `b` immediately adjacent in its input. Now, they are preserved, but the backslash is a literal character in the value of `param`, and the following newline is discarded during word-splitting, so the words `a\` and `b` are output by `echo` separated by a single space.

If you quote `$param`, you'll see the newline.

```
$ echo "$param"
a\
b
```